# Find animals with the highest weight without sorted() (map<String, Animal> (Where Animal - class))

Tags: java, dictionary

I have problem with task. I must find animal with the highest weight but without sorted() in map<String,Animal>. Probles is I cannot get the value body_wt.
I tried to make it through **double maxWeight = (Collections.max(map.));** where map **Map<String, Animal>** but nothing works

Class Animal

```
    package com.company;

public class Animal {
    public double body_wt;
    public double brain_wt;
    public double non_dreaming;
    public double dreaming;
    public double total_sleep;
    public double life_span;
    public double gestation;
    public int predation;
    public int exposure;
    public int danger;

    //getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {

        return "AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt="+getValue(body_wt)+", brainWt="+getValue(brain_wt)+", nonDreaming=" +
                getValue(non_dreaming)+ ", dreaming="+ getValue(dreaming)+ ", totalSleep="+getValue(total_sleep)+
                ", lifeSpan="+getValue(life_span)+", gestation="+ getValue(gestation)+", predation="+predation+", exposure="+exposure+", danger="+danger+"}";
    }

}
```

I read Animals from txt file

```
public static Map<String, Animal> readAnimals(){
    Map<String, Animal> animals = new HashMap <>();
    Scanner devScanner = null;
    try {
        devScanner = new Scanner(new File("mammals.txt"));

        String species = "q";
        devScanner.nextLine();
        while (devScanner.hasNext()) {
            Animal animal = new Animal();
            String nextLine = devScanner.nextLine();
            String[] anData = nextLine.split(";");
            for (int i = 0; i < anData.length; i++) {
                if (anData[i].isEmpty()) continue;
                switch(i){
                    case 0:  species = anData[0];continue;
                    case 1: if(anData[1].equals("NA")){animal.setBody_wt(0);} else{ animal.setBody_wt(Double.parseDouble(anData[1]));} continue;
                    case 2: if(anData[2].equals("NA")){animal.setBrain_wt(0);} else{ animal.setBrain_wt(Double.parseDouble(anData[2]));} continue;
                    case 3: if(anData[3].equals("NA")){animal.setNon_dreaming(0);} else{ animal.setNon_dreaming(Double.parseDouble(anData[3]));} continue;
                    case 4: if(anData[4].equals("NA")){animal.setDreaming(0);} else{ animal.setDreaming(Double.parseDouble(anData[4]));} continue;
                    case 5: if(anData[5].equals("NA")){animal.setTotal_sleep(0);} else{ animal.setTotal_sleep(Double.parseDouble(anData[5]));} continue;
                    case 6: if(anData[6].equals("NA")){animal.setLife_span(0);} else{ animal.setLife_span(Double.parseDouble(anData[6]));} continue;
                    case 7: if(anData[7].equals("NA")){animal.setGestation(0);} else{ animal.setGestation(Double.parseDouble(anData[7]));} continue;
                    case 8: if(anData[8].equals("NA")){animal.setPredation(0);} else { animal.setPredation(Integer.parseInt(anData[8]));} continue;
                    case 9: if(anData[9].equals("NA")){animal.setExposure(0);} else { animal.setExposure(Integer.parseInt(anData[9]));} continue;
                    case 10: if(anData[10].equals("NA")){animal.setDanger(0);} else { animal.setDanger(Integer.parseInt(anData[10]));} break;
                }
            }
            animals.put(species, animal);
        }



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return animals;
}
```

Comment: How about `animalMap.values().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Animal::getWeight))`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can make a static method that takes in an animal[]. Have a currentMax value, initialized to Double.MIN_VALUE and for each index in the array, if arr[i].getWeight() > currentMax -> currentMax = arr[i].getWeight(). Then return the max currentMax at the end. Add an index value if you want the location of it that stores the index of i whenever the currentMax gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different animals that can have extremely high weights, depending on the species and whether they are domesticated or wild. Some examples of animals that can weigh a lot include:

African elephants can weigh up to around 6,000 kg (13,227 lbs)
Blue whales can weigh up to around 200,000 kg (440,925 lbs)
Hippopotamuses can weigh up to around 1,500 kg (3,307 lbs)
Giraffes can weigh up to around 1,200 kg (2,646 lbs)
White rhinoceroses can weigh up to around 2,300 kg (5,071 lbs)
Saltwater crocodiles can weigh up to around 1,000 kg (2,205 lbs)
Keep in mind that this is not an exhaustive list and there may be other animals that weigh even more.**strong text**

Comment: Answer is out of context